# What are some good combinations of libraries?

Tags: opengl, c++, directx9, sfml

Lately I have been working on a game that i plan to make online. I have used different libraries to make this game as far as i could, but I feel that I should rethink on how Im sertting this game up, so I planned to start over. The libraries that I have used are [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/), OpenGL, and [Bullet Physics](http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/), along with [GLM](http://www.3dcodingtutorial.com/Working-with-3D-models/Getting-GLM.html) to load the models.

But the problem is that the 3D graphics arent working with the Physics correctly...

So my main question is:

What would be a good combination of libraries to make an online game with? Im sure that many people have good combinations of libraries for making a game.

The libraries that I would need are ones that fit the criteria of making a simple 3d game(online):

3D Graphics(including a model loader of some sort(if it works with blender that would be even better. I would also like compatability, If Theres one that fits DirectX(at least 9) and OpenGL, then that would be good)

2D Graphics(I liked SFML, so it its possible to get something that works with SFML, that would be nice)

Networking(a way to connect multiple clients to a server/database)

and Physics(Ive worked with Bullet Physics, but I cant find a model setup that would fit with said physics)

Also if there are any other libraries that work well with these I would like to know. Any answers would be very helpful. and details would be even nicer =)

Thanks in advance.
-Molma

Comment: Hey i noticed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90272/game-programming-library-c) in stack overflow. Would you or anyone agree with this combination(Ogre3D)

Comment: Also as other information, I am using Code::Blocks as the IDE and MinGW as the compiler on Windows Vista 32 bit.

Answer (score 4):

> But the problem is that the 3D graphics arent working with the Physics correctly...

Pretty much any pair of graphics and physics libraries will work together. If you haven't managed to get OpenGL graphics and Bullet physics working, you probably just have a bug there which can be fixed.

Comment: hm. alright, but i still need some compatability for different operating systems.

Comment: +1 Both have _full_ compatibility for mac, windows and linux. If you need a different OS add that information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to go put [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) out there. It is, bluntly, amazing at everything you put. Except the networking (No idea, I'm afraid), and weaker on the 2D.

Comment: Unity can definitely do networking (Battlestar Galatica Online uses Unity), though you might have to buy the Pro version.  However, it does *not* work on Linux, so if you need Linux support, it's not a feasible option.